# How to install dogtail script recorder in ubuntu 14?

Tags: scripts, python, automation

According to this tutorial, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation/DogtailTutorial I should have 'Dogtail script recorder' installed in my system after install `python-dogtail` package.

Unfortunately it seems to be not available in the system. I can  only see these binary

```
ls /usr/bin/*dog*
/usr/bin/dogtail-detect-session  /usr/bin/dogtail-run-headless
/usr/bin/dogtail-logout          /usr/bin/dogtail-run-headless-next
```

How can I install the script recorder?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not easy to get this information, but dogtail’s [README](https://gitlab.com/dogtail/dogtail/blob/master/README.md) implicitly states that the "Dogtail Script Recorder" is only available in dogtail version 0.7.x, which is for GNOME 2 only. The newer versions for GNOME 3 and KDE 4.8+ including [v0.8.2 in Trusty’s repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-dogtail) don’t come with the script recorder, which is why you can’t find it. The only way to get it would be to install dogtail version 0.7.x, but neither could I find a download link nor would it work with any desktop environment else than GNOME 2 – maybe with the exception of MATE, but I’m not sure.